# Prove that the limit, $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 1^+} \frac{x-3}{3 - x - 2x^2}$, exists.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

For each of the following, use definitions (rather than limit theorems) to prove that the limit exists. Identify the limit in each case.

d)$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to  1^+}  \frac{x-3}{3 - x - 2x^2}$

Proof: We need to prove the limit exists as $x$ approaches $1$ from the right. 
Let $M$ be a real number. Then we need to show $f(x) > M$, without loss of generality, suppose $M > 0$. Then as $x \to 1^+$, $x-3 \to -2$ and observe the denominator approaches $x \to 0$ as $x \to 1^+$. Also note the parabola has roots $\frac{-1}{2}$ and $1$. Therefore, let $0 < \delta < 1$ such that$ 1 < x < 1 + \delta$
thus, $0 < 3 - x - 2x^2 < \frac{1}{M}$
That is $\frac{1}{3 - x - 2x^2} > M > 0$ then $\frac{x-3}{3 - x - 2x^2} < M$  for all $1 < x < 1 + \delta$

Can someone please help me finish? If it needs work, please help  me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Help you finish? I can't, since what you are trying to prove is quite wrong.

Comment: Then, can you help me?

Comment: Sure: $x-3\to-2$, $3-x-2x^2\to0$, game over.

Comment: I know that. However, I need to use the definition. I need to show f(x) > M

Comment: What level of sophistication do you need?  Is this an intro to analysis course, or a calculus 1 course?

Comment: If you factor the expression, you obtain $$\frac{x - 3}{(3 + 2x)(1 - x)}$$ which approaches $\infty$ as $x \to 1^{+}$.

Comment: This is real analysis. I need to prove it by definition.

Comment: What do you "need to prove" exactly?

Comment: I need to prove f(x) converges to negative infinity, as x approaches 1 from the right if and only if given a real M there is an δ > 0- such that 0 < |x - a| < δ implies f(x) < M. In which case we say f(x) approaches infinity as x approaches 1 from the right.

Comment: The equivalent statement (if the limit $L$ exists) is show for all  $\varepsilon > 0 $ there exists $\delta>0$ such that whenever $|x-1|<\delta$ one has $|f(x) - L | < \varepsilon$.

Comment: This is when L is a finite real value. But here the limit is not a real value. It is negative infinity.

Comment: One cannot "prove [that] f(x) converges to negative infinity, as x approaches 1 from the right if and only if" what follows since what follows is the *definition* of the convergence of f to -oo.

Comment: Just forget about everything. I already turn in the problem about more than hour. Apparently nobody knew how to help abstractly. Just using the technique learned in simple calculus is easy, but in analysis we can't use that.

Comment: Did you read my last comment?

Answer (score 0):

To prove that the limit doesn't exist, it suffices to show that for any $M > 0$, there exists a $\delta$ such that for $0 < x - 1 < \delta$, $|f(x)| > M$. (Then, $f$ is unbounded as $x \rightarrow 1^{+}$.) One way to reverse engineer a proof is find an expression in terms of $\delta$ that will bound $|f(x)|$ as $\delta \rightarrow 0$; using that expression, you can then set $M$ equal to your bound, and deduce what $\delta$ would have to be so that for $0 < x - 1 < \delta$, $|f(x)| > M$. In this process, it is convenient to make certain simplifying assumptions (without loss of generality) to make deducing a bound easier. For instance, you might find it helpful to deduce a bounding expression in terms of $\delta$ that holds when $0 < \delta < 1/4$. (Or, instead of 1/4, pick a convenient upper bound that helps you derive an upper bound; I found 1/4 was convenient for this purpose.)