# Prove that $\lim_{x \to 1^{+}}\frac{x-3}{(3-x-2x^2)} = \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

> prove that $$\lim_{x \to 1^{+}}\frac{x-3}{(3-x-2x^2)} = \infty$$

- Without loss of generality assume that $M>0$ and set $\delta=min \{1,\frac{2}{7M}\}$ such that $1<x<1+\delta$
- Since $1<x<2$ implies $5<2x+3<7$ and $-2<x-3<-1$, It follows that $\frac{1}{2x+3}>\frac{1}{7}$
  thus
  $$\frac{x-3}{2x+3}>\frac{-2}{7}$$
- Since $1<x<1+\frac{2}{7M}$, It follows that $\frac{1}{x-1}>\frac{7M}{2}$
- So $\frac{x-3}{(2x+3)(x-1)}>-M$ that is $f(x)<M$ for all $1<x<1+\delta$

But I want to prove  $f(x)>M$  for all $1<x<1+\delta$

Where am I wrong?

Comment: If not in indeterminate form, then the limit will be undefined (plus or minus infinity).

Comment: related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/955969/prove-that-the-limit-displaystyle-lim-x-to-1-fracx-33-x-2x2?rq=1

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore I saw this but It is not the problem

Comment: Your $\delta$ is wrong which causes a considerable part of the trouble. See my answer with a working $\delta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your solution.

From $\frac{1}{2x+3}>\frac{1}{7}$ and $-2<x-3<-1$ follows

$$\color{blue}{\frac{x-3}{2x+3} < -\frac 17}$$

Here you made two mistakes: You did not flip the relation sign while multiplying by a negative number $x-3$ and you chose the wrong side of the inequality $-2<x-3<-1$.

You never showed how you got your $\delta = \min\{1,\frac 2{7M}\}$ and most probably above mistake in your calculations lead you to choose a wrong $\delta$.

What works is $\color{blue}{\delta = \min\{1,\frac 1{7M}\}}$. So you have for $1<x<1+\delta$

$$\frac 1{x-1} > 7M\Rightarrow \color{blue}{-f(x)}=\frac{x-3}{(2x+3)\color{blue}{(x-1)}} < -\frac 17\cdot 7M = -M$$
Hence,
$$f(x) > M$$

Comment: Very helpful thank you

Answer (score 3):

In your second bullet point, you claim that since $1<x<2$ implies $5<2x+3<7$ and $-2<x-3<-1$, it follows that $\left(\frac{1}{5} > \right) \frac{1}{2x+3} > \frac{1}{7}$ thus
$$\frac{x-3}{2x+3} > \frac{-2}{7}.$$
However, this is not true since we would have
$$\frac{x-3}{2x+3} > \frac{-2}{2x+3} \quad \text{ and } \quad \frac{-2}{2x+3} < \frac{-2}{7}.$$
Therefore, it is unclear $\frac{x-3}{2x+3}$ is greater or smaller than $\frac{-2}{7}$. In fact, we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{x-3}{2x+3} &< \frac{-2}{7}, \quad 1 < x < \frac{15}{11};\\
\frac{x-3}{2x+3} &= \frac{-2}{7}, \quad x = \frac{15}{11};\\
\frac{x-3}{2x+3} &> \frac{-2}{7}, \quad \frac{15}{11} < x < 2.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

You have $0>\frac{x-3}{2x+3}>-\frac27$ if $x\in(1,2)$. You also have $\frac1{x-1}>\frac7{2M}$. But, since $\frac{x-3}{2x+3}<0<\frac1{x-1}$, when you multiply, the inequality gets reversed. Thereby,$$\frac{x-3}{(2x+3)(x-1)}\color{red}<-M.$$

Comment: Did you mean $\frac{1}{x-1}>\frac{7M}{2}$?

Comment: Sure. I've edited my answer. Thanks.

Comment: The inequality $0>\frac{x-3}{2x+3}>-\frac27$ is not true on $(1,2)$. A quick plot reveals this. The OP multiplied with the wrong side of the inequality $-2<x-3<-1$.

Comment: @trancelocation You are right. Normally, I would edit my answer, but I will not do it, since the other answer mentions that.